# Is there a way to more easily combine Expressions and lambdas?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, linq-expressions

Let's say I have an `Expression<Func<Foo, Bar>>` `calculateBar` which 'reduces' a `Bar` into a `Foo`, which I can use like so:

```
IQueryable foo = getFoos();
bars = foo.Select(calculateBar);
```

However, I sometimes need to be able to reference the input Foo, so I want to wrap `calculateBar` so it can return a `Tuple<Foo, Bar>`:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, Tuple<TIn, TOut>>> WithInput<TIn, TOut>(
    this Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn));
    var constructor = typeof(Tuple<TIn, TOut>).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(TIn), typeof(TOut) });

    if (constructor == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, Tuple<TIn, TOut>>>(Expression.New(constructor, param, Expression.Invoke(expression, param)), param);
}
```

Now, that function, in practice, works fine. However, in LINQ-to-Entities, constructors have to be parameterless. So, instead, I might want to create a fake Tuple (`new WithInput<Foo, Bar> { Input = theFoo, Output = theBar }`), but writing that as an expression is going to be rather painful.

Is there a way to build on an existing expression (without upsetting LINQ-to-Entities) using a Lambda instead of continuing to build more `Expression` trees?

For example (psuedocode):

```
Expression<Func<Foo, WithInput<Foo, Bar>>> wrapper = foo => new WithInput { Input = foo, Output = Expression.Invoke(calculateBar, foo) };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a [`MemberInit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344570(v=vs.110).aspx) expression is not so painful compared to what you did for a `Tuple`. Just for the record, it would be something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TIn, WithInput<TIn, TOut>>> WithInput<TIn, TOut>(
    this Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
{
    var parameter = expression.Parameters[0];
    var resultType = typeof(WithInput<TIn, TOut>);
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(resultType),
        Expression.Bind(resultType.GetProperty("Input"), parameter),
        Expression.Bind(resultType.GetProperty("Output"), expression.Body));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, WithInput<TIn, TOut>>>(body, parameter);
}
```

Now on the main subject. It's not possible to build an expression based on an existing lambda without using some custom expression processing utility library (either your own or 3rd party).

For instance, [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) provides `Invoke` and `Expand` extension methods that can be used like this:

```
using LinqKit;

public static Expression<Func<TIn, WithInput<TIn, TOut>>> WithInput<TIn, TOut>(
    this Expression<Func<TIn, TOut>> expression)
{
    return Linq.Expr((TIn input) => new WithInput<TIn, TOut>
    {
        Input = input,
        Output = expression.Invoke(input)
    }).Expand();
}
```